# White space below html, body and footer

Tags: html, css

I am editing a chrome stylish theme for http://kissanime.ru, and I've got everything how I want for now, however there is this space at the end of the page that I cannot figure out how to remove. I have looked around but nothing helps. Also this only happens when on an episode page where the video is shown as well, it doesn't seem to do it on any other page as far as I can tell.

As I do not have the proper html to give, I will say that I have been using the F12 inspect element menu for viewing the html, that's really the best I can give with my current knowledge of editing website css.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/skDIs.png

As you can see there is that big block of space that I can't find out how to remove. Can anyone help me with this?

I also view the page at 110% on chrome btw.

This is the css.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
    }
    html, body {
        background: none !important;
        background-color: #212121 !important;
        height: initial !important;
        font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
    }
    body > #containerRoot {
        min-height: initial !important;                                         
    }
    .divCloseBut {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .bigBarContainer .barTitle {
        display: none;
    }
    .arrow-general {
        display: none;
    }
    .bigBarContainer {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: initial;
        padding: initial;
        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
    }
    .barContent {
        background: none;
        padding: 12px;
    }
    #spanBookmark {
        display: none;
    }
    div#leftside > div:nth-of-type(2) > div.barContent.episodeList > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(-n+6) {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .listing th {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    }
    #containerRoot > div:nth-child(12),
    #containerRoot > div:nth-child(14) {
        display: none !important;
    }
    #fbComments {
        display: none;
    }
    .dotUnder {
        border: none;
    }
    #footer {
        top: initial !important;
        background: none;
        height: initial;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #footcontainer {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footcontainer p {
        margin: initial;
    }
    #head {
        padding-left: 40px;
        width: initial;
    }
    #containerRoot > div:nth-child(11) {
        height: initial !important;
    }
    .banner {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
    }
    .details a img {
        border-color: transparent;
        padding: initial;
    }
    .details a img:hover {
        border-color: #2BAF2B;
    }
    div.items img {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
    div.items img:hover {
        border-color: #A3E9A4;
    }
    #subcontent {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
    }
    #subcontent div div {
        width: 98%;
        background: none;
    }
    #subcontent div div.blue {
        width: 98%;
        background: none;
    }
    #tab-newest div:nth-child(-n+10) div:nth-child(5) {
        display: none;
    }
    #tab-trending div:nth-child(-n+10) div:nth-child(5) {
        display: none;
    }
    #tab-mostview div:nth-child(-n+10) div:nth-child(5) {
        display: none;
    }
    .scrollable {
        overflow-y: initial;
        height: 240px;
    }
    input.text {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        background-color: #333333;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
    #search input.text {
        padding: 4px;
        width: 83% !important;
    }
    #result_box {
        background-color: #333333;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: initial;
        border-bottom-left-radius: initial;
        width: 75%;
        left: 56px !important;
    }
    #result_box a:hover {
        padding: 0px 5px;
        margin-left: -5px;
    }
    #formSearch div:nth-child(3) {
        width: initial !important;
    }
    #formSearch div:first-of-type a:nth-child(n+21) {
        display: none;
    }
    input#imgSearch.button {
        background-color: #B1CA05 !important;
        display: none !important;
    }
    #subcontent div a img {
        padding: initial;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
    #subcontent div a img:hover {
        padding: initial;
        border-color: #A3E9A4;
    }
    .tooltip {
        background: none !important;
        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9) !important;
        height: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        padding: 10px !important;
        font-size: 13px !important;
    }
    .tooltip div:first-of-type {
        width: 400px !important;
    }
    #navsubbar {
        background: none;
        width: 1729.3px;
    }
    #navsubbar p {
        background: none;
        width: 969.3px;
    }
    #navcontainer li a#currentTab {
        background: none;
        background-color: #42BD41;
    }
    #navcontainer a:link, #navcontainer a:visited {
        background: none;
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        width: 106.789px;
    }
    #navcontainer a:hover {
        background: none;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
    div.pagination {
        margin: initial;
    }
    div.pagination ul.pager li {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
        background: none;
        background-color: white;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
    div.pagination ul.pager li a {
        padding: 4px 8px;
    }
    div.pagination ul.pager li a:hover {
        background: none;
        background-color: #999999;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
    div.pagination ul.pager li.current {
        background: none;
        background-color: #999999;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
    #formSearch div:nth-of-type(3) a img {
        display: none;
    }
    #topHolderBox {
        background: none;
        padding-top: initial;
        width: initial !important;
    }
    #topHolderBox img {
        display: none;
    }
    .bigChar {
        color: #72D572;
        letter-spacing: normal;
    }
    a {
        color: #72D572;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #A3E9A4;
    }
    #tabmenucontainer li a.tabactive {
        color: #FFF;
        background: none;
        background-color: #42BD41;
    }
    #tabmenucontainer a:link, #tabmenucontainer a:visited {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        background: none;
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
    }
    #tabmenucontainer a:hover {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        background: none;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
    #tabmenucontainer li {
        text-indent: unset;
    }
    #tabmenucontainer ul {
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
    }

    /*font change start*/
    h1, h2, h3, h4 {
        font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
    }
    .details {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    .bigChar {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    #navcontainer ul {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    #tabmenucontainer ul {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    #subcontent div div {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    .title {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    #subcontent span.title {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    #topHolderBox {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    input.text {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    #result_box {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    /*font change end*/

    #result_box a {
        line-height: normal;
    }
    .listing tbody tr td a:hover {
        color: #A3E9A4;
    }

    #nextEpisodeCountDown {
        color: #72D572 !important;
    }
    .episodeList td a:visited {
        color: #216E21;
    }
    .specialButton {
        border-radius: 0px !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        background: none !important;
        font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
        background-color: #42BD41 !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
    .specialButton:hover {
        background-color: #349433 !important;
    }
    #containerRoot > div:nth-child(20) {
        background-color: #212121 !important;
    }
    select {
        border: 1px solid #393939;
    }
    button#playerChoose {
        border-radius: 0px !important;
        text-shadow: none;
        background-color: #42BD41;
    }
    button#playerChoose:hover {
        background-color: #349433;
    }
    .barTitle {
        background: none;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        letter-spacing: normal;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 13px;
        background-color: #42BD41;
    }
    .scrollable_title {
        letter-spacing: normal;
    }
    a.prev, a.prev:hover {
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/hrwRsig.png);
    }
    a.next, a.next:hover {
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/xaR51zB.png);
    }
    #navbar {
        background: none;
    }
    #navsubbar p {
        background-color: #42BD41;
    }
    div.navi {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    #divAds, #divAds2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .alphabet {
        background: none !important;
    }
    #footcontainer p a:hover {
        color: #A3E9A4;
    }
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(11) {
        border: none !important;
        background: none !important;
    }
    #divComments > div:first-child > div:nth-child(2),
    #leftside > div.bigBarContainer:nth-child(7) > div.barContent.episodeList > div:nth-child(2) > div:first-child {
        color: #D32F2F !important;
    }

    .rightBox {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6);
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#rightside > div.rightBox:first-child .barContent div:nth-child(2) {
    color: #D32F2F !important;
}

    /* ad/div hider start */
    iframe#adsIfrme1,
    iframe#adsIfrme6,
    iframe#adsIfrme7,
    iframe#adsIfrme8,
    iframe#adsIfrme9,
    iframe#adsIfrme10 {
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
    }
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(2),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(3),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(4),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(9),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(17),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(20),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(22),
    .barContent > div:only-child > div:nth-child(23) {
        display: none !important;
    }
    /* ad/div hider end */


    /* extra space removel */
#adsIfrme7 {
    height: 0 !important;
}

#adsIfrme10 > div.clear {
    height: 0 !important;
}

#head h3 {
    margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

#topHolderBox {
    margin: -25px 0 0 0;
}

#formSearch > div:nth-child(3),
#formSearch > div:nth-child(4) {
    margin: -100px 0 0 0 !important;
}

#containerRoot > div:nth-child(18) {
    height: 75px !important;
}

.clear,
.clear2 {
    height: 0 !important;
}
    /* extra space removel end */
```

Comment: please give us only the necessary css. and we need the html code for knowing the strucutre

Comment: I have been using the F12 menu for looking at the html for now. I will update the question with this info.

Comment: and to reply to sysix I do not know what is necessary and what is not for the css. If I built the css myself I would know but I am just using a theme that was built by someone else and am editing it for my own wants.

Answer (score 0):

What is the style name? I'm at the userstyles.org right now. Tell me the theme and I'll try to fix it locally.

**UPDATE:**
Nvm, found it. It's "Minimal KissAnime". To remove the black "big block of space", go to the style and add this code:

```
.video-js {
 background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I guess I misunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about the video player. Yeah, when you scroll down, there's a lot of space, almost like a full page. The thing is, when I scrolled up again (without refreshing), and then scrolled down again, there was no such huge space. Personally I think it's because of the ads that are loading and are not loaded correctly. I'm sorry, but I don't think it's the style problem, it's the webpage itself.

Comment: its this one https://userstyles.org/styles/136663/minimal-kissanime-fixed-by-dark-mind its an edited one that fixes some pictures and stuff. sorry for late reply, btw that code you said didn't work for me unless I didn't put it in the right place. by style i assume you mean to just add it to the end of the css?

Comment: Yeah, when you want to modify someone's else style, you put your code at the end. Also, as I mentioned, I don't think it's the style problem, but the page itself. Scroll up and down without refreshing, and that space will be gone. Probably because of ads.

Comment: I've tested again, and I don't even need to scroll up and down. Just wait for the page to finish loading, and everything will be ok.

Comment: Yeah I really cant figure this out. i just tried disabling my adblockers so see this full page thing you talked about, and i got the same thing. if you install ublock origin and disable any other adblocks and only use ublock then it will look the same as my screenshot.

Comment: and i think i just figured out why its doing it. if i turn my adblockers off, then the ad shows with it hitting the bottom of the page, and thats whats pushing the body down. If you turn the adblockers back on, then the ad is gone but the pushing down by the ad still remains